# Why do the elements in my array show up as undefined?

Tags: typescript

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why I can't get the information out of the array

```
const usedPlatformLog: Date[] = []
users.forEach(el => {
    usedPlatformLog.push(el.lastUsed)
})
console.log(usedPlatformLog) // shows array with indexes 0 and 1 (picture attached)
console.log(usedPlatformLog[0]) // log response undefined
```

Comment: *"shows array with indexes 0 and 1"* - What data does the first `console.log` show for those indexes?

Comment: This problem is not reproducable with the given code. You are probably doing stome `async` stuff inside the function that you are not showing us. You can't use `async` with `.forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined` is a valid value, and can be pushed into arrays.

your array is `[undefined, undefined]` probably because `users[0].lastUsed` and `users[1].lastUsed` are also undefined. Maybe `console.log(users)` so you can actually see what's in that array.